# Are 2Rx4 DDR2 ECC memories compatible with Intel Xeon on socket LGA771?

Tags: memory, intel, xeon, ecc

For my Intel Xeon L5420 (LGA771) I bought 24GB of DDR2 ECC Reg, 2Rx8, knowing that 2Rx4 are specific to AMD chipsets or, at least, the non-ECC ones are.

However, this slick seller instead sent me 2Rx4, the cheaper ones. Will these work nonetheless on a 771 Xeon?